# If input value is "something" add onclick to the button

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick

Add `onclick` event on button if value of input field is "Greece" or "UK" else no `onclick` event.

```
<form class="search-options">
    <input id="test" type="text" value="" />
</form>
<button id="search-button">Search</button>
<script>
    $('.search-options').find("input[value='greece']").each(function(){
        document.getElementById("search-button").onclick = "Suggestion.submit();";
    });
</script>
```

If input value is Greece or UK, then button should have onclick="Suggestion.submit();"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If user enter "Greece" or "UK" in input, in button must be added onclick="Suggestion.submit();"

Answer (score 0):

You need to store event listeners inside as functions:

If you don't need to pass arguments, then:

```
document.getElementById("search-button").onclick = Suggestion.submit;
```

Or, if you want to pass pre-defined arguments, then use this format:

```
document.getElementById("search-button").onclick = function(){Suggestion.submit(argument1, argument2, argumentN)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to have different callbacks per value, what you are really after is a single callback which will then act differently depending on the value (or call different functions). Add this callback to every input onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onclick, use addEventListener click

```js
    $('.search-options').find("input[value='greece']").each(function(){
        document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener('click',function(){console.log("submitted")})
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search-options">
    <input id="test" type="text" value="france" />
    <input id="test2" type="text" value="greece" />
    <input id="test3" type="text" value="UK" />
    <input id="test" type="text" value="spain" />
</form>
<button id="search-button">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer to use it like that:

```js
document.querySelector('#search-button').onclick = function(){
    if(document.querySelector('#test').value == 'Something'){           
          document.querySelector('form span').innerText = document.querySelector('#test').value;
         //do more
    }else{    
          document.querySelector('form span').innerText = 'cancel click';
          return false;
         }
}
```

```html
<form class="search-options">
    <input id="test" type="text" value="" />
    <span></span>
</form>
<button id="search-button">Search</button>
```